# Merging Stack Exchange Accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange

How do I merge my Stack Exchange accounts, or more accurately – how can I use the same profile on http://gaming.stackexchange.com and here (Super User), as well as probably other sites in the 'family' without creating a new 'account' for each?

Comment: Thanks for the editing/english lesson [slhck](http://meta.superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)! ;)

Comment: I'm also looking a way to merge accounts. I had different accounts in different servers here and it was a big mess. Now I just do not use the old ones any more but would be great to merge them with their points, badges and links to posts and comments. I tried to add their authentication methods to my new account but it didn't help either

Comment: @Cougar Maybe ask a new question with more details so your issue is more visible to the people who can actually help.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is answered on our big parent Meta site, Meta Stack Overflow:

> #### [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)
>
> […] follow this procedure:
>
> Set the email address of your registered account to the address used
>   in your other account. Since email is not visible to anyone, this will
>   confirm that you own both accounts.
>
> Edit: Some people have had trouble with this step. If you have two
>   registered accounts and cannot make the email addresses the same, an
>   alternative option is to make a note in one of the profiles: "Please
>   merge this account into ."
>
> Flag one of your posts for moderator attention and ask for a merge.
>
> If the details match, we will go ahead and merge with no further ado.
>   If we feel we need more confirmation for some reason, we will either
>   comment or email to tell you.

Comment: Thanks [slhck](http://meta.superuser.com/users/48078/slhck)! You're rapidly turning into my mentor! Will try this today/tomorrow and report back :)

Comment: I'm glad to help! If you have any problems in the process, the best way would be to visit our [Ask a Super User Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) chatroom!