# Integrate reputations of multiple superuser accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I have 2 accounts on superuser.
May I know how can I transfer and integrate the reputations of my accounts?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Merging Stack Exchange Accounts](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3748/152004)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [Contact Form](https://meta.superuser.com/contact) (available in the footer of every page on Stack Exchange sites) and select "Account Issue" and then the reason "I need to merge user profiles".

You will need to provide links to both accounts and then an email should be sent to both accounts registered email to confirm ownership.

If that does not work then again you will have to use the contact form to contact staff directly.

Comment: Thank you @Mokubai, this is what I'm looking for, I'll try with the Contact Form.